# CloudMade + Android

Tags: android, cloudmade

Good afternoon,

i write in order to ask a question about the use of the API KEY. I'm developing an application for Android, so i use the service provided for www.nutiteq.com for using the api maps.
But the problem is the following:

when i use the code proposed by nutiteq:

```
    mapComponent = new BasicMapComponent("115f89503138416a242f40fb7d7f338e4b73e583e8e343.19717285", 
            "TouristEye", "TouristEye", 1, 1,
            new WgsPoint(mCenter.getLong(), mCenter.getLat()), 10);
    mapComponent.setMap(new CloudMade(" 24c1c76c612248f7acd23978088bfb3a", 64, 1));
```

the API Key i ask for Cloud Made doesn't work correctly and i can't use the maps. I selected mobile use when i get the Api key and have passed more than hour since i asked for it.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Did you need to give the website the Certificate Fingerprint or MD5 in order to get your api key?  If so then you need to know that it's different if you're loading the app on to the device using eclipse or if you're creating a signed apk.

Comment: Try to remove 'space' before API-key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public CloudMade(java.lang.String licenseKey,
             java.lang.String userid,
             int tileSize,
             int mapLayout)
```

You must add your userid after your licenseKey.

bye